# How to calculate dynamic % of grand total as a measure on Power BI?

Tags: optimization, powerbi, formula, calculated-field

I have the below table connected into Power BI and I am looking for ways to create a formula calculating % of grand total of the Rating column and further subtracting with targets for each rating. For example, the % of grand total for Rating 1 is 3 divided by 7 (42.86%). The most important part of the formula is the denominator which has to remain at a total level and dynamic for any filters applied to either Grade or BU columns. For example, denominator at a total level would be 7 and when filtered down to Academy BU should be 3.

**Sample Data Table:**
[image: data table]

**Rating Target Table:**
[image]

I want the end result to look like this,
[image: end result]

I have used the following formula to achieve this,

Measure created: `% of total calc = DIVIDE(COUNT('Table'[Rating]),CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Count]),'Table'[Rating]))`

To make the above formula work I had to add an extra column and include ones in it (see below)
[image]

I want to know if there are other ways of achieving this outcome?

Answer (score 0):

ALLEXCEPT will produce such result  to exclude used dimensions and include mandatory filters such as date with one condition, rating, date, any dimension must be in the same  table.